# Wild problem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Is classification of a pair of linear operators $A$, $B$, $A^2=B^2=0$, up to simultaneous conjugation a "wild" problem? Reference?

Equivalently, is it possible to classify finite-dimensional representations of $k\langle x,y \rangle /\langle x^2,y^2 \rangle $, up to equivalence?

Comment: How is this different from the problem of classifying operators which satisfy $A^2 = 0$?  The problem, if I understand it correctly, is easily approached using Jordan form

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "simultaneous conjugation".

Comment: I said "up to simultaneous conjugation". It is known that this problem is wild for a pair of matrices and tame if A^2=B^2=AB-BA=0

Comment: So to get a classification "up to simultaneous conjugation", assume without loss of generality that $A$ is in its Jordan normal form, and $B$ is any matrix satisfying $B^2 = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That is not a classification. Even if you put $A$ to have all its non-zero blocks at the beginning of the diagonal, you still have non-trivial conjugations that fix $A$. Therefore, two different $B$ can be in the same class.

Comment: I added an equivalent formulation of the problem. This might clear up any confusion.

Comment: @arugula thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Jeff thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s tame.

This is proved by Bondarenko in “Representations of dihedral groups over a field of characteristic two”, *Math USSR, Sbornik*, vol 25, no. 1, (1975) 58-68.

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1975v025n01ABEH002197/meta

This result works in any characteristic. It’s only the applications to dihedral groups that require characteristic two.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I cannot upvote - it requires 15 points :-(

Comment: @Jeff I’ll forgive you. :-) If this completely answers your question then I think that even with your meagre collection of points you can still “accept” the answer, so that other people can see that it has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: I have 21 points now :-). I accepted the answer. Thanks again!